# xpath error in the php code - Invalid Expression

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am getting this error,

`Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Invalid expression`.

Searched in internet but could not remove this error. That is im posting it one more time.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
            $file = $_POST['id'];
            $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

            $user = $xml->xpath("user[user_id == $id]");             
            $name = $user->name;
            $file = $user->file;
            echo 'Name' . $name;
            echo 'File Name' . $file;
?>
        <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method="POST">
            Login ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>               
        </form>
```

And my test.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <user>
        <user_id>0121</user_id>
        <name>Tim</name>
        <file>0121.file</file>
    </user>
    <user>
        <user_id>0178</user_id>
        <name>Henry</name>
        <file>0178.file</file>
    </user>
    <user>
        <user_id>0786</user_id>
        <name>Martin</name>
        <file>0786.file</file>
    </user>
    <user>
        <user_id>1239</user_id>
        <name>Jan</name>
        <file>1239.file</file>
    </user>
</document>
```

Any reason?

Thanks
Raaks

Comment: The answer is already posted below, but keep in mind that it's very difficult to google syntax questions. You should have just went straight to the spec, where you would have easily found your answer: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` is the invalid expression. Try this:

```
 $user = $xml->xpath("user[user_id=$id]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath (`=` instead of `==`):

```
user[user_id = $id]
```